Estimation of a gamma function-like integral
A random variable $X$ has a pdf: $$f(x) = \frac{1}{k!} \cdot x^k \cdot e^{-x}$$
Prove that $$P(0<X<2\cdot(k+1)) > \frac{k}{k+1}$$
There are no conditions about $k$, so it can be non-integer.
I did these steps:
$$P(0<X<2\cdot(k+1)) = \int_0^{2k+2} \frac{1}{k!} \cdot x^k \cdot e^{-x} dx = \frac{1}{k!} (\int_0^{+\infty} x^k \cdot e^{-x}dx - \int_{2k+2}^{+\infty} x^k \cdot e^{-x}dx) = \frac{1}{k!} (Г(k+1) - \int_{2k+2}^{+\infty} x^k \cdot e^{-x}dx) = 1 - \frac{1}{k!} \cdot \int_{2k+2}^{+\infty} x^k \cdot e^{-x}dx$$
How can the second integral be estimated to show the required inequality?

the property is probably true for all $k > 0$ but you need to replace the factorial by the Gamma function (I'm not sure for $-1 < k < 0$)

Two directions I see. 1. The distribution is log-concave. Can we perhaps bound the log by an affine function / the proba by an exponential? 2. Integration by parts

Look up the incomplete gamma functions.

@GuillaumeDehaene, yes, assume that $k>0$

Have you tried to take advantage of Markov's inequality ?

This is probably not the simplest answer. We need to show that
$$
\frac{1}{{k!}}\int_{2k + 2}^{ + \infty } {x^k {\rm e}^{ - x} {\rm d}x}  < \frac{1}{{k + 1}}
$$
for $k>-1$. (I simply define $k!$ by $\Gamma(k+1)$ for non-integer $k$.) We perform the change of variables from $x$ to $t$ via $x = 2(k + 1){\rm e}^t$ to obtain
$$
\frac{1}{{k!}}\int_{2k + 2}^{ + \infty } {x^k {\rm e}^{ - x} {\rm d}x}  = \frac{{(2{\rm e}^{ - 1} )^{k + 1} }}{{k!}}(k + 1)^{k + 1} {\rm e}^{ - (k + 1)} \int_0^{ + \infty } {\exp \left( { - (k + 1)(2{\rm e}^t  - t - 2)} \right){\rm d}t} .
$$
By $(5.6.1)$, we have
$$
(k + 1)^{k + 1} {\rm e}^{ - (k + 1)}  < \frac{{(k + 1)!}}{{\sqrt {2\pi (k + 1)} }}
$$
for any $k>-1$. By Maclaurin series expansion, we can see that
$$
2{\rm e}^t  - t - 2 \ge t
$$
for any $t\ge 0$. Therefore,
$$\tag{1}
\frac{1}{{k!}}\int_{2k + 2}^{ + \infty } {x^k {\rm e}^{ - x} {\rm d}x}  < (2{\rm e}^{ - 1} )^{k + 1} \frac{{\sqrt {k + 1} }}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\exp \left( { - (k + 1)t} \right){\rm d}t}  = \frac{{(2{\rm e}^{ - 1} )^{k + 1} }}{{\sqrt {2\pi (k + 1)} }}
$$
for any $k>-1$. I leave it as an exercise to show that
$$
\frac{{(2{\rm e}^{ - 1} )^{k + 1} }}{{\sqrt {2\pi (k + 1)} }} < \frac{1}{{k + 1}},
$$
for any $k>-1$. Let me add that by Stirling's formula and the Laplace method, it can be shown that
$$
\frac{1}{{k!}}\int_{2k + 2}^{ + \infty } {x^k {\rm e}^{ - x} {\rm d}x}  \sim \frac{{(2{\rm e}^{ - 1} )^{k + 1} }}{{\sqrt {2\pi (k + 1)} }}
$$
as $k\to+\infty$, whence the bound $(1)$ is sharp.
